# How to merge a dependent entity from a dependent entity with many-to-one relations

Tags: typescript, foreign-keys, nestjs, typeorm

I have a main entity that has a OneToOne relation with a second entity:

```
@Entity('main_entity')
export class MainEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  @IsInt()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(
    () => SecondEntity,
    (second) => second.main,
  )
  second: SecondEntity;
}
```

And I have a second entity that has a OneToMany relation with a third entity:

```
@Entity('second_entity')
export class SecondEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @IsInt()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => MainEntity)
  @JoinColumn()
  main: MainEntity;

  @OneToMany(() => ThirdEntity, (third) => third.secondEntity)
  third: ThirdEntity[];
}
```

And I also have a third entity, which is related to the second ManyToOne relations:

```
export class ThirdEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  @IsInt()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @Length(1, 255)
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => SecondEntity, (second) => second.id)
  second: SecondEntity;
}
```

Attention question:
When filtering the data in response, I want to get all the dependent entities using queryBuilder, but I can’t think of how to unify the third one.
How can I get the third entity from the "main" queryBuiler if main doesn't know anything about the third?
Relations chain looks like this:
`main knows only about second, second knows about main and third, and third knows only about second`

```
   const query = await this.createQueryBuilder('main')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('main.second', 'second')
   .leftJoinAndSelect('second.third', 'third')
```

I have tried many options like the one above but with no success

Answer (score 0):

the error was in the names of the alias, I thought it was not working because of the ManyToOne relation, it turned out that I just re-specified the same alias.